# Q: How does one show that in a prefibred category, if composition of weak Cartesian maps is weak Cartesian, then we have a fibration?

Tags: category-theory

I'm studying from Bart Jacobs' Categorical Logic and Type Theory for an undergraduate project, and I'm having trouble with a part of Problem 1.1.6. Let $p:\mathbb{E}\to\mathbb{B}$ be a functor. I need to show that $p$ is a fibration if

- (a) every morphism $u:I\to pY$ in the base category $\mathbb{B}$ has a weak Cartesian lifting $f:X\to Y$; and
- (b) the composition of two weak Cartesian morphisms is again weak Cartesian.

What I have tried is as follows: fix $Y\in\mathbb{E}$, and $u: I\to pY$ then by (a) there exists some weakly Cartesian map $f:X\to Y$ above $u$. We want to show that $f$ is Cartesian. Indeed, let $g:Z\to Y$ and $v:pZ\to I$ such that $pg=u\circ v$, then by (a) there exists some weakly Cartesian morphism $h: W\to X$ above $v$. To summarize, in $\mathbb{E}$ we have:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    W @<\exists!j<< Z\\
    @V h V V @VV g V\\
    X @>>f> Y
\end{CD}
above the following diagram in $\mathbb{B}$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    pW @= pZ\\
    @V v V V @VV pg=u\circ v V\\
    I @>>u> pY
\end{CD}
then by (b) the morphism $f\circ h$ is weakly Cartesian, so that there exists a unique $j: W\to Z$ making the above diagram commute. Then $h\circ j$ is one such map so that
$g = f\circ(h\circ j)$.

What remains to prove $f$ is Cartesian is to show that this map is unique, and this is the part I have trouble with. While $j$ is unique, $h$ need not be, and I cannot find a reason as to why $h\circ j$ is unique. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

P.S. This is my first time posting on Stack Exchange, if I did break any rules I apologize in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I understand, but tikz-cd does not work in MathJax and I have no idea how to type up this particular commutative diagram in my post. I will try to figure it out in the meantime, but thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/446262).

Comment: Alright, I have done the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that if $k : Z→X$ is any morphism such that $f∘k=g$ and $pk = v$, then since $h$ is weakly cartesian, there is a unique $j' : Z→W$ such that $h∘j' = k$. We also get $f∘h∘j' = g$, so that $j=j'$ because $f∘h$ is weakly cartesian. Hence $k = h∘j' = h∘j$.

PS: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I think there is a mistake in the statement of this exercise 1.1.6. In the definition of weak cartesian morphism, we should suppose that $ph=\operatorname{id}_X$. Otherwise it is not unique.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't u derstamd the second paragraph of needing $ph=id_X$ though. Did you mean $ph=id_I$?

Comment: @Somebody I'm speaking about the definition of weak cartesian morphisms in Jacobs' book, exercise 1.1.6. It's with the notation there. There are examples of fibration where the $h$ is not unique if we don't require that. In your question, it would mean we have $pj = \operatorname{id}_Z = \operatorname{id}_W$.

Comment: In the book, Jacob defines a morphism to be vertical if it is above some identity morphism in $\mathbb{B}$, is that perhaps what you meant?

Comment: @Somebody Ah, thanks, this is it! I only read the exercise and thought "vertical" wasn't a technical term.